# Using Django's built-in ssi template tag, causing 500 error

Tags: python, django, settings, ssi

I'm trying to use Django's built-in template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#ssi

It says:

> Note that if you use {% ssi %}, you’ll need to define ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS in your Django settings, as a security measure.

Whenever I set ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS to anything in my settings.py, it causes every page on the website to produce a 500 error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you set `settings.DEBUG = True` to show more info?

Comment: Not really, the site is live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem was just a mistake in the value I had for ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS.